# Can you conditionally fail a Hive script?

Tags: hive

I want to conditionally fail a hive script. Like if there is no data in certain table, the script should fail, otherwise proceed. I know this may not be ideal solution but for some reason this is my requirement. Since HQL is not procedural language, it is a challenge.

Comment: Did you try the old "division by zero" trick, e.g. `select 1 / count(*) from WTF`? Or, in case `count(*)` yields a false result because of statistics -- _yes, that's true, some shitheads have decided that HQL should produce false results, and have used "static" statistics for that purpose; I'm not making that up_ -- and the table is a standard table backed by HDFS, then `select 1 / count(distinct INPUT__FILE__NAME) from WTF`

Comment: it doesn't fail -- if you divide by zero it simply returns NULL :(

Comment: `select reflect("java.lang.System", "exit", 1);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**assert_true**

```
hive> select assert_true (2>1);
OK
NULL
Time taken: 2.61 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

---

```
hive> select assert_true (2<1);
OK
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: ASSERT_TRUE(): assertion failed.
Time taken: 1.063 seconds
hive>
```

---

**Demo**

myscript.sql

```
set hive.cli.errors.ignore=false; -- this is the default

select 'checkpoint 1';

drop table t1;
create table t1 as select 1;
select assert_true(count(*)>0) from t1;

select 'checkpoint 2';

drop table t2;
create table t2 as select 2 where false;
select assert_true(count(*)>0) from t2;

select 'checkpoint 3';

drop table t3;
create table t3 as select 3;
select assert_true(count(*)>0) from t3;

select 'checkpoint 4';
```

---

```
bash-4.1$ hive -f myscript.sql 2>/dev/null
checkpoint 1
NULL
checkpoint 2
bash-4.1$
```

Comment: `assert_true(false)` seems to keep trucking in scripts (via `-f` or `source`). `select reflect("java.lang.System", "exit", 1);` always stops